# Apache Server Reverse Proxy with ProxyPreserveHost On results in 404

Tags: java, apache, web, proxy

I'm hoping someone here with experience with `Apache` can help me out.  I have an internal server, that I'm fronting with `Apache Reverse Proxy`.  i.e.

- **Apache Server:** https://www.myexternalserver.com
- **Internal Server:** https://www.myinternalserver.com

#### Apache Settings

```
<Proxy *>
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
</Proxy>

RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} ^TRACE
RewriteRule .* - [F]

ProxyVia Off
ProxyRequests Off
ProxyPreserveHost On

SSLProxyEngine On
SSLProxyCheckPeerCN Off
SSLProxyCheckPeerExpire Off
SSLProxyCheckPeerName Off
SSLProxyVerify none

ProxyPass               /internal   https://www.myinternalserver.com
ProxyPassReverse        /internal https://www.myinternalserver.com

<Location />
        Allow from all
#       Require all granted
</Location>
```

The problem I'm having is such:

- The internal application in code uses `getRequest().getServerName()` to get the url.  If I turn off `ProxyPreserveHost` and set it to `Off`, then the internal application ends up being the url that is returned.  This is not what I want since this internal application url is not accessible to the public.
- From what I've read, `ProxyPreserveHost` needs to be `On` so that the `Apache Reverse Proxy` can pass it's url to the underlying internal applications.  When I do this however, I get a 404.  I understand that what is probably happening is that the internal server is using the external domain to find its application and thus cannot find it.  I'm not sure how to get around this.  Btw, the internal application is hosted on `PCF`.

I would appreciate it if someone could help me out.

Thanks!

Comment: Hi Kabir! I am facing pretty much the same issue (getting 404 when ProxyPreserveHost is turned on). Have you found a solution?